# digital certificate vs rsa key

Tags: rsa, ssh-keys, client-certificates

I am going through a document about "password vs digital certificate". I read that unlike the password, a certificate can not be stolen due to public private key use. However, does it mean if we use RSA public/private (ssh-key gen to create this pair) to access ssh server using ssh client, it can not be stolen? What if I take shared public key from one client machine to my client machine and install. Will I be not able to log in to the same ssh server? How ssh server will know that client req is coming from a different machine when public ssh key is same?

Answer (score 0):

> However, does it mean if we use RSA public/private (ssh-key gen to create this pair) to access ssh server using ssh client, it can not be stolen?

A public key is only useful when it's used with the corresponding private key. **As long as the private key is kept safe**, the connection is secure, no matter who knows the public key.

> What if I take shared public key from one client machine to my client machine and install. Will I be not able to log in to the same ssh server?

Assuming the server has enabled public-key authentication and disabled password authentication, then the answer here will depend on whether you have the corresponding private key. If you have the private key, then yes, you can log in. If you don't have the private key, then no, you cannot log in.

> How ssh server will know that client req is coming from a different machine when public ssh key is same?

The server usually already has the public key; the client needs the corresponding private key to authenticate. Beyond that, the server will be able to track different network conditions (IP addresses, TCP parameters, etc.) and SSH internals (algorithms for key exchange, message authentication, etc.) to distinguish between client machines.